# Loop Efficiency in Lists in Python 3.9

Tags: python-3.x

So I have a program that needs to take a JSON file and sorts on the list according to that JSON file and then spits out the stored list wherever told. But the code just looks like it could be more efficient, but there is nothing that I can thing of that would make it better. Here is the code:

```
import json

shopping_list = ["canned tomatoes", "bread", "eggs", "milk"]

isle2_items = []
isle3_items = []
isle4_items = []
isle5_items = []
isle6_items = []
isle7_items = []
isle8_items = []
isle9_items = []
isle10_items = []
isle11_items = []
isle12_items = []
isle13_items = []
isle14_items = []
isle15_items = []
isle16_items = []
isle17_items = []

with open("isleTypes.json") as f:
    data = json.load(f)

#fun with for loops
for i in range(2, 17):
    for j in range(len(data[f'_{i}'])):
        for item in shopping_list:
            if item == data[f'_{i}'][j]:
                if i == 2:
                    isle2_items.append(item)
                elif i == 3:
                    isle3_items.append(item)
                elif i == 4:
                    isle4_items.append(item)
                elif i == 5:
                    isle5_items.append(item)
                elif i == 6:
                    isle5_items.append(item)
                elif i == 7:
                    isle7_items.append(item)
                else:
                pass

for index in isle2_items:
    print(index)

#print(data['_2'][2])
```

Of course in the for loop, in the chain of if's it would be longer, but that is also one of the problems.

Comment: can you partly/fully share your example json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import json
from collections import defaultdict

shopping_list = {"canned tomatoes", "bread", "eggs", "milk"}

isle_items = defaultdict(list)
with open("isleTypes.json") as f:
    data = json.load(f)

#fun with for loops
for isle_number in range(2, 17):
    for json_item in data[f'_{i}']:
        if json_item in shopping_list:
            isle_items[isle_number].append(json_item)

for item in isle_items[2]:
    print(item)
```

Converted shopping_list to `set` so it will have constant lookup time.
Removed branching instead used defaultdict, which basically has an empty list for non-existing keys.

Comment: @SudoAptWhyUPDATE no problem. you can tag it as answer if you'd like